# Average latency of atomics cmpxchg instructions on Intel Cpus

Tags: multithreading, x86, atomic, lock-free

I am looking for some reference on average latencies for lock cmpxchg instruction for various intel processors. I am not able to locate any good reference on the topic and any reference would greatly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Think of it as read+write to main memory. OTOH, probably Ulrich Drepper's "What every programmer should know about memory" has more details.

Comment: what are you doing that requires knowing the average latency, beyond morbid curiosity?

Comment: @MSN: not much beyond morbid curiosity...i am in research :-) ... basically figuring out if apps with fine-grained synchronization have an chance on multi-cores and if so when....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few, if any, good references on this because there is so much variation. It depends on basically everything including bus speed, memory speed, processor speed, processor count, surrounding instructions, memory fencing and quite possibly the angle between the moon and Mt Everest...

If you have a very specific application, as in, known (fixed) hardware, operating environment, a real-time operating system and exclusive control, then maybe it will matter. In this case, benchmark. If you don't have this level of control over where your software is running, any measurements are effectively meaningless.

As discussed in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585825/do-atomic-operations-become-slower-as-more-cpus-are-added), locks are implemented using CAS, so if you can get away with CAS instead of a lock (which will need at least two operations) it will be faster (noticeably? only maybe).

The best references you will find are the [Intel Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), though since there is so much variation they won't give you an actual number. They will, however, describe how to get the best performance possible. Possibly a processor datasheet (such as those [here](http://www.intel.com/design/corei7ee/documentation.htm) for the i7 Extreme Edition, under "Technical Documents") will give you actual numbers (or at least a range).

Comment: Thanks Zooba, this helps. I looked at the datasheet but could find  reference to cmpxchg type instruction. The reason for my question was because this operation  performed  ok on core-i3 and horribly on Xeon's...wasn't sure why was this case..and therefore was looking for some reference...

Comment: The instruction "lock cmpxchg" _is_ CAS on the x86.

Comment: FWIW, not all locks require two `CAS` operations. Many locks on x86 are implemented with a `CAS` or `xchg` on the acquire path, but a simple store on the unlock path. The x86 memory model is strong enough for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

The best x86 instruction latency reference is probably that contained in [Agner's optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals), based on actual empirical measurements on various Intel/AMD/VIA chips and frequently updated for the latest CPUs on the market.

Unfortunately, I don't see the `CMPXCHG` instruction listed in the instruction latency tables, but page 4 does state:

> Instructions with a LOCK prefix have a long latency that depends on cache organization and possibly RAM speed. If there are multiple processors or cores or direct memory access (DMA) devices then all locked instructions will lock a cache line for exclusive access, which may involve RAM access. A LOCK prefix typically costs more than a hundred clock cycles, even on single-processor systems. This also applies to the XCHG instruction with a memory operand.

Comment: I think this is outdated. I remember once I've made such tests. I remember that starting from Intel Core Duo processors the *cost* of `lock` prefix dropped to about 45 cycles.

Comment: It is lower than 45 cycles now. I just benchmarked LOCK INC - and it is just under 35 cycles (when uncontested)

Comment: Agner lists latency/throughput/uop-counts for `lock cmpxchg`, `xchg [mem], reg`, and a couple others.  That's the best-case, though, and doesn't reflect the impact on loads/stores in the surrounding code from the memory barrier, or the *average* cost when there's even light contention (e.g. it costs cycles if the current CPU doesn't have the line in `M` state of MESIF/MOESI, even if the `cmpxchg` succeeds on the first try.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use AIDA64 software to check instruction latencies (but you cannot check which of the instructions to check, it has a hard-coded list of instructions). People are publishing the results at http://instlatx64.atw.hu/

From the `lock` instructions, AIDA64 verifies the `lock add` instructions and `xchg [mem]` (which is always *locking* even without an explicit lock `prefix`).

Here are some info. I will also give you, for comparison, latencies of the following instructions:

- `xchg reg1, reg2` which is not locking;
- `add` to registers and memory.

As you see, the *locking* instructions are just 5 times slower on Haswell-DT and just ~2 times slower on Kaby Lake-S than non-locking memory stores.

### Intel Core i5-4430, 3000 MHz (30 x 100) Haswell-DT

```
LOCK ADD [m8], r8         L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
LOCK ADD [m16], r16       L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
LOCK ADD [m32], r32       L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
LOCK ADD [m32 + 8], r32   L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
LOCK ADD [m64], r64       L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
LOCK ADD [m64 + 16], r64  L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c

XCHG r8, [m8]             L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
XCHG r16, [m16]           L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
XCHG r32, [m32]           L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c
XCHG r64, [m64]           L: 5.96ns= 17.8c  T: 7.21ns= 21.58c

ADD r32, 0x04000          L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.09ns=  0.36c
ADD r32, 0x08000          L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.09ns=  0.36c
ADD r32, 0x10000          L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.09ns=  0.36c
ADD r32, 0x20000          L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.08ns=  0.34c
ADD r8, r8                L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.05ns=  0.23c
ADD r16, r16              L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.07ns=  0.29c
ADD r32, r32              L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.05ns=  0.23c
ADD r64, r64              L: 0.22ns=  0.9c  T: 0.07ns=  0.29c
ADD r8, [m8]              L: 1.33ns=  5.6c  T: 0.11ns=  0.47c
ADD r16, [m16]            L: 1.33ns=  5.6c  T: 0.11ns=  0.47c
ADD r32, [m32]            L: 1.33ns=  5.6c  T: 0.11ns=  0.47c
ADD r64, [m64]            L: 1.33ns=  5.6c  T: 0.11ns=  0.47c
ADD [m8], r8              L: 1.19ns=  5.0c  T: 0.32ns=  1.33c
ADD [m16], r16            L: 1.19ns=  5.0c  T: 0.21ns=  0.88c
ADD [m32], r32            L: 1.19ns=  5.0c  T: 0.22ns=  0.92c
ADD [m32 + 8], r32        L: 1.19ns=  5.0c  T: 0.22ns=  0.92c
ADD [m64], r64            L: 1.19ns=  5.0c  T: 0.20ns=  0.85c
ADD [m64 + 16], r64       L: 1.19ns=  5.0c  T: 0.18ns=  0.73c
```

### Intel Core i7-7700K, 4700 MHz (47 x 100) Kaby Lake-S

```
LOCK ADD [m8], r8         L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
LOCK ADD [m16], r16       L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
LOCK ADD [m32], r32       L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
LOCK ADD [m32 + 8], r32   L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
LOCK ADD [m64], r64       L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
LOCK ADD [m64 + 16], r64  L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c

XCHG r8, [m8]             L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
XCHG r16, [m16]           L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c
XCHG r32, [m32]           L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.20ns= 21.83c
XCHG r64, [m64]           L: 4.01ns= 16.8c  T: 5.12ns= 21.50c

ADD r32, 0x04000          L: 0.33ns=  1.0c  T: 0.12ns=  0.36c
ADD r32, 0x08000          L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.12ns=  0.37c
ADD r32, 0x10000          L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.12ns=  0.36c
ADD r32, 0x20000          L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.12ns=  0.36c
ADD r8, r8                L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.11ns=  0.34c
ADD r16, r16              L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.11ns=  0.32c
ADD r32, r32              L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.11ns=  0.34c
ADD r64, r64              L: 0.31ns=  0.9c  T: 0.10ns=  0.31c
ADD r8, [m8]              L: 1.87ns=  5.6c  T: 0.16ns=  0.47c
ADD r16, [m16]            L: 1.87ns=  5.6c  T: 0.16ns=  0.47c
ADD r32, [m32]            L: 1.87ns=  5.6c  T: 0.16ns=  0.47c
ADD r64, [m64]            L: 1.87ns=  5.6c  T: 0.16ns=  0.47c
ADD [m8], r8              L: 1.89ns=  5.7c  T: 0.33ns=  1.00c
ADD [m16], r16            L: 1.87ns=  5.6c  T: 0.26ns=  0.78c
ADD [m32], r32            L: 1.87ns=  5.6c  T: 0.28ns=  0.84c
ADD [m32 + 8], r32        L: 1.89ns=  5.7c  T: 0.26ns=  0.78c
ADD [m64], r64            L: 1.89ns=  5.7c  T: 0.33ns=  1.00c
ADD [m64 + 16], r64       L: 1.89ns=  5.7c  T: 0.24ns=  0.73c
```

Comment: How are you getting a factor of 5 for HSW and a factor of ~2 for KBL?  Things are almost identical.  Did you compare throughput for HSW but latency for KBL?  Or were you comparing to a pure store instruction which you didn't list?  (`ADD [m32], r32` is not just a store, it's an RMW).  Also note that a `lock`ed instruction is a full memory barrier, which means it has more cost if there were a lot of loads + stores in the surrounding code, so looking at just the no-contention throughput of `lock`ed instruction doesn't give the real picture.

Comment: For anybody else confused about the throughput (`T`) value, it describes `the time that it takes for the next independent same-type instruction to start`, as documented [here](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/master/Comments.htm).

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into exponential backoff for a few months now.

The latency of CAS is utterly dominated by whether or not the instruction can operate from cache or has to operate from memory.  Typically, a given memory address is being CAS'd by a number of threads (say, an entry pointer to a queue).  If the most recent successful CAS was performed by a logical processor which shares a cache with the current CAS executer (L1, L2 or L3, although of course the higher levels are slower) then the instruction will operate on cache and will be fast - a few cycles.  If the most recent successful CAS was performed by a logical core which does not share a cache with the current excutor, then the write of the most recent CASer will have invalidated the cache line for the current executor and a memory read is required - this will take hundreds of cycles.

The CAS operation itself is very fast - a few cycles - the problem is memory.

Comment: "and a memory read is required" not so, the access is still from the cache, but the cache line needs to be acquired in shared mode (it was previously in exclusive mode in the other processor).

Comment: Intel CPUs since Nehalem use a large *inclusive* shared L3 cache which backstops coherence traffic, so it should just need a round trip through L3.  This is still slow, especially on a multi-socket system.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to benchmark CAS and DCAS in terms of NOP.

I have some results, but I don't trust them yet - verification is ongoing.

Currently, I see on Core i5 for CAS/DCAS 3/5 NOPs.  On Xeon, I see 20/22.

These results may be completely incorrect - you were warned.

Comment: Note these values are when the data used in is the cores L1 cache.

Comment: CAS means compare and swap? DCAS means double compare and service and NOP means?

Comment: CAS is single word CAS.  DCAS is contigious double-word CAS.  NOP is the No Operation instruction.

Comment: thanks, could you share a link talking about CAS you mentioned. I find some with compare and swap and some with compare and set...

Comment: CAS is a generic acroynm.  Intel for example call this "Compare and Exchange" - http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/cmpxchg.htm

Comment: CAS, despite being called "compare and swap", combines a compare with a *STORE* operation; while it indicates whether the compare matched (implying the store was performed) it does not indicate what value was read that resulted in a compare mismatch.  While it would be possible to fetch the value after a failed compare-and-store and retry the CAS operation if the old value reappeared between the failed CAS and the fetch, that may have some livelock scenarios which an atomic compare-exchange operation would not.