# Concurrent linked queue use CAS

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I found this code segment about concurrent linked queue in IBM Developer.

But I can't understand a part of them. Which is

```
while(true){
    ...
    if(curTail == Tail.get()){
        if(residue == null){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

According to the define of curTail and residue, I think curTail is a copy of Tail and curTail is a pointer equals Tail.next .

I concern that function compareAndSet will judge if the caller object is equal to the first param, why must judge them before call this function? I think the code below can so the same thing well.

```
        while (true) {
            Node<E> curTail = tail.get();
            Node<E> residue = curTail.next.get();
                if (curTail.next.compareAndSet(null, newNode)) /* C */ {
                    tail.compareAndSet(curTail, newNode) /* D */ ;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    tail.compareAndSet(curTail, residue) /* B */;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
public class LinkedQueue <E> {
    private static class Node <E> {
        final E item;
        final AtomicReference<Node<E>> next;
        Node(E item, Node<E> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = new AtomicReference<Node<E>>(next);
        }
    }
    private AtomicReference<Node<E>> head
        = new AtomicReference<Node<E>>(new Node<E>(null, null));
    private AtomicReference<Node<E>> tail = head;
    public boolean put(E item) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(item, null);
        while (true) {
            Node<E> curTail = tail.get();
            Node<E> residue = curTail.next.get();
            if (curTail == tail.get()) {
                if (residue == null) /* A */ {
                    if (curTail.next.compareAndSet(null, newNode)) /* C */ {
                        tail.compareAndSet(curTail, newNode) /* D */ ;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    tail.compareAndSet(curTail, residue) /* B */;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the code try to avoid calling "compareAndSet" as possible. Probably it cost more... some link I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183202/java-compare-and-swap-semantics-and-performance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187914/average-latency-of-atomics-cmpxchg-instructions-on-intel-cpus

Comment: @Surely Thanks for your tips. I just focus the logic of the code but neglect the cost of CAS.......

Comment: I am not quite sure whether it is the case though. Waiting for someone who is better at this topic to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference: example, code explanations of the algorithm are available on [this page from the IBM Developer website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04186/).

The page linked above will give you the purposes of each operation **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**, and why they are required to allow what is referenced therein as *constructive interference* between threads concurrently updating the tail of the queue.

Your change corrupts the algorithm. The `else` clause must *not* be executed when **C** is unsuccessful. The role it plays instead is to reproduce the operation **D** when a thread intercepts an uncompleted [*] update of the tail from another thread.

[*]: That is, after **C** but before **D**.

To understand why and when it fails, consider the following scenario.

```
while (true) {
   Node<E> curTail = tail.get();
   Node<E> residue = curTail.next.get();

   /* (i) */

   if (curTail.next.compareAndSet(null, newNode)) /* C */ {
     tail.compareAndSet(curTail, newNode) /* D */ ;
     return true;
   } else {
      tail.compareAndSet(curTail, residue) /* B */;
   }
}
```

- Two threads **T1** and **T2** start simultaneously at position **(i)**. Their stack holds the same references for `curTail` and `residue`. `residue` is supposed `null` (i.e. the queue is supposed to be in quiescent state).
- **T1** completes the first CAS **C** successfully. It does not execute **D** yet.
- **T2** fails the CAS **C**, enters the `else`, executes CAS **B** successfully, since the reference `tail` hasn't changed.
- **T1** fails the CAS **D**, since the reference assigned to `tail` has been set to `null` by **C**. There is no fallback, and the method exits. Element from **T2** is not inserted.
- Second attempt for **T1**, the reference assigned to `tail` is `null` and `curTail.next` throws a `NullPointerException`. The data structure is corrupted.

To summarize, **A** and **B** works in pairs. They exist to ensure interfering threads can help the convergence of the queue to a *normal* state and recover from a queue left in an *intermediate* state. Imagine a thread executes **C** but gets killed before having a chance to run **D**. Without **A** and **B**, the queue would be forever corrupted. **A** and **B** ensures the state can be reconstructed and the unfinished insertion completed.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks very much for the detailed explain.